# Wordpress - add_filter passing function vars

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a premade function which looks like so:

```
function truncate($string='', $limit='150', $break=" ", $pad="...") {
```

I need to pass the `$limit` argument, but can't figure out how.
I'm calling the `add_filter()` as well, as follows:

```
add_filter('the_content','truncate');
```

I want to pass `20` as the `$limit`.

For the life of me, I can't figure how.

Any help?

Cheers,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass additional parameter to wordpress filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753484/how-to-pass-additional-parameter-to-wordpress-filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's something for this within Wordpress, but the easy option is to create a new function:

```
function content_truncate($string) { return truncate($string, 20); }
add_filter('the_content', 'content_truncate');
```

If you're using PHP >= 5.3 you might be able to use an anonymous function to make it a bit neater:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($string) { return truncate($string, 20); });
```